# Bluetooth connection in Background as a Service in Android?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I am developing an application in which Android device will be connected to a device via bluetooth and they will be exchanging certain packets. Now, the packet communication should be running in background and user can navigate through the screens of the app. So, for this purpose using bluetooth communication running as service is proper solution or not? If not, then can someone let me know of alternative to it.

One more thing that I wanted to know is whether its a good idea to have the service as "Remote" and communicate over IPC or the Service should be running in the same process as Application.

Comment: Have you done the code for this? I have been looking for an Android bluetooth service everywhere but nothing. Would you be so kind to post the code?It will help a lot

Comment: @Iker: Could you get soln for this.Even I need some source code for reference to run BT in the background.If yes,then pls share

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a perfectly good solution. Actually, I think service components are exactly for this kind of work. Be sure to check on wake locks too, if you don't want to lose connection when the phone gets in suspended mode.

Comment: Thanks, for confirming that is the proper way of doing.

Comment: @sunil: can you pls share the source code.Would be helpful for the whole community.Also,did you have to make use of wake locks to keep the connection active?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is a perfectly good solution. 
You need to define Service in AndroidManifest file.

```js
<application android:name="com.example.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="com.example.BLEService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```