# Bluetooth disconnects in android ViewPager application

Tags: android, android-fragments, arduino, bluetooth, android-viewpager

I am currently working at mobile app written in Kotlin that enables the user to remotely control a robot via bluetooth.I have MainActivity class that hosts 3 fragments: FragmentMain inside where my bluetooth interface is defined, FragmentCamera and FragmentDisplayText.
This is my pager adapter class:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> FragmentMain()
            1 -> FragmentCamera()
            2 -> FragmentDisplayText()
            else -> FragmentMain()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

My problem is that, when I swipe between screens and reach the third one, bluetooth connection closes. I don't know why it does happen.

This is my MainActivity where i set an adapter for a ViewPager:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
        val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
        val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }
}
```

And this is how my bluetooth interface works:

```
/* ============================ Thread to Create Bluetooth Connection =================================== */

    inner class CreateConnectThread(private val activity: Activity, private val context: Context, private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter, private val address: String) :
        Thread() {

        init {
            val bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
            var tmp: BluetoothSocket? = null
            var uuid: UUID? = null

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                uuid = bluetoothDevice.uuids[0].uuid
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                    ), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }

            try {
                tmp = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed", e)
            }
            if (tmp != null) {
                mmSocket = tmp
            }
        }

        override fun run() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
                try {
                    mmSocket.connect()
                    Log.e("Status", "Device connected")
                    handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1).sendToTarget()
                } catch (connectException: IOException) {
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close()
                        Log.e("Status", "Cannot connect to device")
                        handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1).sendToTarget()
                    } catch (closeException: IOException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException)
                    }
                    return
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                    ), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
            connectedThread = ConnectedThread(mmSocket)
            connectedThread.start()
        }

        fun cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e)
            }
        }
    }

    /* =============================== Thread for Data Transfer =========================================== */

    inner class ConnectedThread(socket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread() {
        private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket = socket
        private val mmInStream: InputStream
        private val mmOutStream: OutputStream

        init {
            var tmpIn: InputStream? = null
            var tmpOut: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.inputStream
                tmpOut = socket.outputStream
            } catch (_: IOException) {
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn!!
            mmOutStream = tmpOut!!
        }

        override fun run() {
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytes = 0
            while (true) {
                try {
                    buffer[bytes] = mmInStream.read().toByte()
                    var readMessage: String
                    if (buffer[bytes] == '\n'.toByte()) {
                        readMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                        Log.e("Arduino Message", readMessage)
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, readMessage).sendToTarget()
                        bytes = 0
                    } else {
                        bytes++
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        fun write(input: String) {
            val bytes = input.toByteArray()
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("Send Error", "Unable to send message", e)
            }
        }

        fun cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone any ideas what may have been done wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

I tried to swap FragmentCamera and FragmentDisplayText but the result was the same, the bluetooth connection is established, it works when I swipe to second screen and crashes when I swipe to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be happening because your Bluetooth activity is attached to the screen, therefore when you navigate from that screen, the Bluetooth functionality is terminated. The solution to this would be to manage the Bluetooth activity in a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Some references:-

- [Bluetooth connection gets lost in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896923/bluetooth-connection-gets-lost-in-android)
- [Bluetooth connection in background as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232147/bluetooth-connection-in-background-as-a-service-in-android)
- [Android Bluetooth LE GATT example](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt)
- [React native - how to maintain BLE on page navigat](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/622)